# Android Target SDK vs Build SDK

Tags: android

In what scenarios would the Target SDK version and Build SDK version ("Compile with" in screen below) differ?

[image: SDK version settings]

I'm trying to figure out why Target SDK wouldn't be used for both providing the API level the application is designed to run on, as well as compiling against the same SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In what scenarios would the Target SDK version and Build SDK version ("Compile with" in screen below) differ?

When the developer sets them to be different values.

> I'm trying to figure out why Target SDK wouldn't be used for both providing the API level the application is designed to run on, as well as compiling against the same SDK.

At the point in time when you create a new project, setting the build SDK and the target SDK to be the same is reasonably common, which is why that's the default in the new-project wizards.

However, developers may well want to raise the build SDK to a newer API level, while leaving the target SDK alone. The target SDK version controls some elements of forwards compatibility and therefore may change things that the developer is not ready to address just yet.

For example, suppose a developer created an app in mid-2013, and at that time set both the build SDK and the target SDK to be 18. Then, early this year, the developer started poking around with Android 4.4 (API Level 19). The developer wanted to add printing capability to her app. The simplest way to support API Level 19 printing is to set the build SDK to 19, so she could reference the relevant classes directly. However, KitKat also changed the behavior of classic `AlarmManager` methods like `set()` and `setRepeating()`, and she decides that she's not ready to deal with that just yet. Since [those changes are tied to the target SDK version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#KITKAT), she leaves her target SDK version on 18 for the time being, making a note to work on supporting the new inexact nature of `AlarmManager` alarms in the future. Hence, at this point, her build SDK is 19 and her target SDK is 18.

Answer (score 0):

Target SDK: Highest API level that the application have been tested. The application should be compatible with all the devices with this API level or more recent API.

Compile with: API level with the application have been compiled. For default it's the highest possible level (now it should be Android 4.4.4 kit kat)